# Database Table design for Weekdays and Values

Tags: database-design

I would love to here your ideas on this. I am creating a table which will store weekly shift hours for employees.

for example: Jon works 9:00am to 9:00pm Monday , 10:00 AM to 5:00PM on Tuesday, etc.

How should I go on designing this table? I thought of 2 options.

(1) For every record I can have two lines for AM and PM and have columns for Monday to Sunday

```
ID | ParentID | Type | Monday | Tuseday ......Sunday
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1        | AM  | 9:00    | 9:00          12:00
2  | 1        | PM  | 9:00    | 5:00          02:00
3  | 2        | AM  | 10:00   | 
4  | 2        | PM  | 10:00   |
```

(2) I can save Preference in XML format in one column

```
ID | Info
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | |Hours|Monday|9:00 AM - 9:00PM|Monday|Tuseday........|Hours
```

Any better ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: You have to ask yourself: will the recursion of shifts always happen on the same day of the week? Will the shifts sometimes reoccur every 10 days...?

Comment: these are contractors so there is no gurentee of any sort...it can be different every day of the week or not different at all. This will be daily schedule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, if I was to design the database I would decide on wether the information is purely stored in the database for use in the application, or would there be queries written against this data.

I have found that storing XML data is a nice way of storing application data, that will be used by the application.

When I know that there will be queries written to these fields, it is more cumbersome using XML, So then I would rather use a normal table structure.

*So, it would depend on what the use of this data will be, and if you intend on writing queries, creating reports from these fields.*

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This data will be inserted and queried against from the website. There is going to be a portal behind it. I guess I am kind of confused on how to store this type of data. I know that days of the week are constatns. It can only be monday to sunday. So should i just created 7 columns in the table and store the values accordingly ?

Comment: Yes, seeing as they are constant, you can go for that. For scalibility (which in this case i might not see a use of) you could create it vertically instead of horizontally. Create a DayType which would be a Foreign key in the table, but as you said, it will only be Mon - Sun in your case, so **KISS** **Keep It Simple Stupid** X-)